# Fundamental group of $M_g^\circ$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, coarse-moduli-spaces

Let's work over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. Let $g\geq3$ be an integer. Let $\mathcal{M}_g$ be moduli stack of smooth genus $g$ curves. Let $M_g$ be the corresponding coarse moduli scheme. They share an open subscheme $M_g^\circ$ parametrizing  automorphism-free smooth genus $g$ curves.

What is the fundamental group $\pi_1(M_g^\circ)$?
How does it compare to the following notions:

(1) The orbifold mapping class group $\pi_1(\mathcal{M}_g)$,

(2) The topological fundamental group  $\pi_1(M_g)$,

(3) The mapping class group of a genus $g$ surface, $\mathrm{Mod}_g$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Except in a few trivial cases, the locus of curves which have an extra automorphism will have codimension greater than one in $\mathcal M_g$. When that happens, the fundamental group of $\mathcal M_g$ must equal the fundamental group of $\mathcal M_g^{\circ}$. (To see this, one can pass to the $3$-torsion cover of $\mathcal M_g$, which is a smooth scheme, and use the fact that removing a codimension two subscheme of a smooth scheme does not affect $\pi_1$.) So it equals cases 1 and 3.

Comment: For completeness: the locus of curves with automorphisms is of codimension $g-2$.

Comment: What happens when $g=3$?

Comment: @KevinCasto I don't know except it seems that, because the hyperelliptic locus has nontrivial class in $H^2$, the abelianization of $\pi_1$ does not increase except possibly by some torsion when it is removed.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks! Do we know if (1) coincides with (2)? (Since $M_g$ is normal, finite etale covers are determined by integral closure in the function field extension?)

Comment: @Qixiao As Paul Johnson has already explained, $\pi_1(M_g)$ is trivial while $\pi_1(\mathcal M_g)$ is not. The normalcy is completely correct, but the issue is simply that some finite extensions of the function field are ramified as covers of $M_g$ but unramified as covers of $\mathcal M_g$.

Answer (score 11):

Since $\mathcal{M}_g=[\mathcal{T}_g/\text{Mod}_g]$, and $\mathcal{T}_g$ Teichmüller space is contractible, (1) and (3) are going to be isomorphic.

This was mentioned previously on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194521/isomorphism-between-a-mapping-class-group-and-the-fundamental-group-of-a-moduli), or can be found for instance on page 361 of Farb and Margalit "A primer on Mapping Class Groups".

Meanwhile, (2), the fundamental group of the coarse moduli space $\pi_1(M_g)$, is trivial, as described by Andy Putman's answer to a question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223877/is-the-moduli-space-of-graphs-simply-connected).

So, we really just need to compare $\pi_1(M^\circ_g)$ to $\pi_1(\mathcal{M}_g)$.  The inclusion map will give us a homomorphism from $\pi_1(M^\circ_g)\to \pi_1(\mathcal{M}_g)$, and presumably we can say something nice about this but I don't know anything off the top of my head and have run out of time to research it...

Comment: I dream that someday mathematicians will learn how to spell my name...

Comment: @AndyPutman Thanks for the explanation on triviality of $\pi_1(M_g)$ in that answer!

Comment: @AndyPutman Argh how embarrassing.  So sorry.  Question was interesting to me because it was on the edge of what I knew, but had already spent too long tracking down answers I did find to pay attention to basic things like formatting or getting people's names right.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: Don't worry, you're not the first to make that mistake...